# How to store data once in localstorage with navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage when there are multiple tabs or windows?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store stringified objects sent by my service worker in localstorage.

My service worker uses firebase cloud messaging to receive messages from my server.

The messages are objects with two properties: an id(an int referencing the person who sends the message) and some text(a string).

When my service worker receives a message, it is sent to all its clients(which are all the webpages of my webapp that are in different tabs or windows).

Then I use a function to store the message in an array stored in localstorage by using a key so that multiple messages can be stored.

My problem is that the message is stored multiple times when there are multiple tabs or windows with my webpages on them but I want that the message gets stored only once.

Also, the message doesn't get stored by the number of times there is a new tab or window. It usually only gets stored twice even if there are three or more tabs with my webpages on them.

On all of my webpages there is a function assigned to navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage that listens to the service worker when it sends a message to the webpages.

This function stores a new message in localstorage each time the service worker sends one.

The process for storing a new message is the following:

- First, the function parses an object, containing the array with the messages, from localstorage with JSON.parse().
- Then, the array pushes the new message.
- Finally, the object with the array is stringified with JSON.stringify() and then stored in localstorage in order to update the old one.

In order to prevent that this process is not repeated by the number of times there is a new tab or window, I tried using a boolean in the function where the service worker sends the message to all its clients so that only one of them gets the message to store it but it doesn't work...

Here is how the service worker gets the message:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var messaging=firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
    var message=JSON.stringify(payload.data);
    send_message_to_all_clients(message);
});
```

Here is how the service worker sends the message:

```
function send_message_to_all_clients(msg){
    var sendMessage=true;
    clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
        if(sendMessage){
            send_message_to_client(client, msg).then(m => console.log("SW Received Message: "+m));
            sendMessage=false;
        }
        })
    })
}

function send_message_to_client(client, msg){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

    msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
        if(event.data.error){
            reject(event.data.error);
        }else{
            resolve(event.data);
        }
    };

    client.postMessage(msg, [msg_chan.port2]);
    });
}
```

And here is how the client stores the message in localsotrage:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage= function(event){
    var key,messages,newMessage;
    newMessage=event.data;
    key="messagesFromServer";
    if(localsotrage[key]){
        messages=JSON.parse(localsotrage[key]);
        messages.array.push(newMessage);
    }else{
        messages={
            array:[]
        };
        messages.array.push(newMessage);
    }
    localstorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(messages));
}
```

I want that when my service worker receives a message, the message is sent to only one of my webpages so that the message isn't stored multiple times.

Also, I know I used a function that sends the message to all of the clients of the service worker but I don't know if there is a way to send the message to only one unspecific client so that no matter how many tabs or windows with my webpages there are, the message is stored only once.

Comment: Would it be an option to send the message to all clients, and check the array client-side if that ID exists, and if so just do nothing?

Comment: Sadly no, the id references the id of a person sending the message(i'm going to edit that thanks) and not the message so if it does nothing if the id is not there in the first place, then the message will never be stored.

Comment: I guess you could do it dirty and just check if there is any message in the array with `id === id && text === text` and then skip? Might not be the best, but it would prevent duplicates. Unless of course there might be duplicated that are supposed to be there.

Comment: Well I can't really prevent people from sending the same message twice even at different time periods but thanks for the suggestion.